# Как восстановить образ жесткого диска, созданного программой dd?

Tags: linux, резервное-копирование, hdd, восстановление

Создавался образ HDD с помощью команды

```
dd if=/dev/sda conv=sync,noerror bs=512K | gzip -c | dd bs=512K of=hdd.img.gz
```

Пробую восстановить командой

```
gzip -cd hdd.img.gz | dd bs=512 of=/dev/sda
```

В самом конце выполнения выводит ошибку о том что последняя запись не может вместится на устройство из-за того что размер образа диска на 1 запись больше размера устройства, на которое происходит восстановление. При использовании bs=512 вроде бы это можно игнорировать, однако разделы на жестком диске не появляются, хотя образ является копией всего устройства, по идее в том числе MBR. Не понимаю, как восстановить бэкап?

Comment: что именно значит «разделы на жестком диске не появляются»? не видны в `fdisk`'е? или просто `partbrobe` сделать забыл?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, вообще не видит структуры gparted

Comment: с виду всё правильно... только вот в принципе если диск правильного размера, то он не должен был бы выдавать предупреждение... а в остальном не вижу, что могло пойти не так...

Comment: Вот и я без понятия, жесткий диск тот же, с которого снимал бэкап пару месяцев назад. Что можно в этом случае предпринять? Может бэкап можно как-нибудь примонтировать, чтобы вынять хотя бы файлики?

Comment: можно распаковать, и подключить файл `losetup`'ом на устройство `/dev/loop*`, но это не многое даст...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение оказалось банальным: Повторить команду заново, и все восстановилось без ошибок